Server Error During Google Login on Moodle
An error is displayed to users trying to login to the Moodle website. The thing is the error is not showing for everyone.
It started to show for users that are registering through login but now it is showing for registered and unregistered users.
It is working fine with many other users.
Nothing related shows up in the server logs
500 Error
I tried storing sessions on database but it didn't change anything. acually it started showing errors for registered users randomly
